# Read internal hard drive externally on Windows

Tags: hard-drive, drivers, external-hard-drive

Recently swapped out a good laptop HDD with an SSD. Hooked up the old HDD with an external HDD enclosure and plugged it into a USB port on my Linux box - everything works fine. 
Next, I unplugged it and plugged it into my Windows - doesn't recognize it/requests a format.

So, am I missing some drivers to read the HDD on Windows? Or perhaps some software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also an interesting issue on some hard drives where Windows 7 attempts to read the hard drive and in doing so corrupts the hard drive such that it's unreadable. You will know this is happening if after plugging it into Windows 7, it no longer works in Linux.

I discovered the solution to this specific problem:
Run chkdsk to fix the corruption and Win7 will detect the device again.

1. Press Start-R (or "Run" from start menu)
2. Type cmd to run command prompt
3. Run command chkdsk [DISK NAME] /r (ex. chkdsk g: /r)

In my specific case, this resolved the problem and Windows was able to properly detect the hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

Software like data rescue DD would probably do the trick.

Alternatively you could install Linux on the computer, boot into it, and perform file transfers there.

Don't know of any "native" solutions to this problem.

Comment: What's going on here? Why are you answering your own question?

Comment: People come here for reference so I like to put my current solutions up for people to peruse. I made the question so I can find better answers. <3 stackexchange.

Comment: @sawdust it's perfectly fine, accepted and [encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) to answer your own questions